# Why can't use jProfiler to test remote service?

Tags: java, jprofiler

Set remote FQDN(Ex: https://my.service.com) with port. But can't connect to it, always hanging.

But remote server's **8849** port is opening:

```
$ sudo lsof -i:8849
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    29279 jira   14u  IPv4 7722212      0t0  TCP *:8849 (LISTEN)
```

[image]

Comment: Any output on stderr for the remote process? There should be lines prefixes with `JProfiler>` if there is a connection attempt. Otherwise, do you maybe have an outgoing firewall on the machine where the JProfiler GUI is running that blocks the JProfiler executable?

Comment: @IngoKegel I didn't find that process on remote server. Now there isn't a firewall for it.

Comment: You could try to connect the the `bin/jpcontroller` command line executable directly on the remote server to check if it works locally.

Comment: I tried it on remote server: `/opt/jprofiler/bin/jpcontroller`, got `Error: Could not find or load main class install4j.com.jprofiler.cli.ControllerApplication`.

Comment: You probably just copied the jpcontroller start script. However, it requires some files from the bin and the lib directories of a JProfiler installation. Please extract the .tar.gz distribution of JProfiler on the remote server, then all these files will be available.